# Jquery Fancybox autoscale not working as intended?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

So in my Fancybox I dont want a scrollbar displayed but rather use the autoscale : true option.

So what happens with my settings is that no scroll bar is displayed which is good, but the contents of the div go outside of the white div of the fancybox and the div itself does not grow to size of the content but stays at its original size.

```
claimLink.fancybox({
        'scrolling' : 'no',
        'overlayShow' : false,
        'autoScale' : true,
        'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        'hideOnContentClick' : false,
        'width': 500,
        'height': 590,
        'autoDimensions': false,
        'onCleanup': function (e) {

            var modelClaimFormId = $j(e).attr("href").replace("body", "");
            var modalClaimForm = $j(modelClaimFormId);

            if (!($j(modalClaimForm).valid())) {
                $j(claimForm).remove();
                $j(e).parents("tr").remove();
            }

        }..
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `'autoScale' : true` does is to make fancybox to fit in the viewport. The is the intended use of it.

If you want fancybox with specific fixed dimensions, in this case `'width': 500` and `'height': 590` then set `autoScale` to `false`.

On the other hand `autoDimensions` is used to set (get) the size of fancybox from the content itself; such content should have dimensions though (a `<div>` with `width` and `height` for instance), otherwise it would produce unexpected resuls ... in that case you don't need to set either `width` or `height` fancybox API options, however `autoScale` should be set to `false` to display the content in its full size, otherwise fancybox will be scaled to fit in the viewport and scroll bars would appear.